# jQuery help for checking if the asyc behavior is accomplished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which has a jQuery.post being done, with POST parameters passed to it.

```
function executeFunction(){
   jQuery.post("../somefile.php", {executeFunction:true});

 }
```

If I'm not wrong, this is async behavior.

Elsewhere in the code, I have:

```
executeFunction(function(){
        jQuery('#box').reload();
    });
```

After the async behavior is done, I need to take the action of jQuery('#box').reload();

How do I put a check to see if the async behavior has been accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This third argument to [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is the callback function, it runs when your data comes back, like this:

```
function executeFunction(callback) {
  jQuery.post("../somefile.php", {executeFunction:true}, callback);
}
```

In the above example the pair `executeFunction=true` is being passed to the server, if that wasn't your intent and you just want to post no data, it looks like this:

```
function executeFunction(callback) {
  jQuery.post("../somefile.php", callback);
}
```

Also, that callback receives a few parameters if you need to use them, the data (server response), the status, and the XmlHttpRequest, so you can do this for example:

```
executeFunction(function(data) {
  //use data, it's what the server sent back
  jQuery('#box').reload();
});
```